# Process Builder - Invalid cross reference ID error with queue assignment

Tags: process, builder

I am getting invalid cross reference ID error when process builder fails to assign the right queue to a case record. This happens only when new queues and process builder gets deployed  to a new environment . If I edit the process builder action and update the queue field   in new environment, Issue will be resolved. I am aware that the process builder tries to keep the queue ID of older environment at backend and tries to look for same ID in new environment. I am looking for some suggestions on how to avoid this without manually editing the process builder in new environment.

Thanks
Vish

Answer (score 2):

**Quick Fix is:**

Please do the following things.

```
1) Clone the process builder in new org.
2) Then Delete the owner Id row.
3) Again add the owner Id row which was previously set.
```

**This will re-reference your owner Id to the new org and the error will be gone.**

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you did not deploy the queues between the environments but re-created them. I found that I had this same problem, but only with some queues. When I did some research, I found that deployed queues actually retain the id from the deploy source org in the deploy target org.

Answer (score 0):

we have to create custom label and store Queue ID there and use custom label in process builder. So we don't have to modify process builder after deployment.